# How to run Xquartz in rootless mode?

Tags: xquartz

Is here any way to run the `Xquartz` in rootless mode?

So when start e.g. `xterm`, will get only one `xterm` window without the whole black screen background?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the Xquartz preferences. Have clicked the "full-screen" mode. Unclicked it and all working nicely, without the black screen.